# Right alignment of imakeidx in general index

Tags: makeindex

I'm trying to align rightly the `imakeidx section` in the general index. I'm using (most relevant):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[title=\'Indice de t\'erminos]
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,total={170mm,257mm},left=20mm,top=20mm}

\usepackage{parcolumns}

\usepackage{anysize}
\marginsize{3cm}{3cm}{3cm}{3cm} %Márgenes {izquierda}{derecha}{arriba}{abajo}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\indexname}{\'Indice de t\'erminos}

\clearpage
\pagestyle{empty}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\'Indice de t\'erminos}
\printindex
```

I obtain this:

[image]

I want every item appear with same "margin" size (I use red line). The item corresponding to imakeidx is a little out.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Welcome! What do you mean by “to align rightly”?

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](//tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).